# bytebuddy: make array of generic

Tags: java, byte-buddy

i want to make class:

```
class Clazz<T>{
 T[] value;
}


TypeDescription.Generic t1 = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.typeVariable("T").asArray().build();

new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class)
            .typeVariable("T")
            .defineField("value", t1, Modifier.PUBLIC)
            .make()
```

but i get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A symbolic type variable does not imply an erasure: T
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$Symbolic.asErasure(TypeDescription.java:5802)
```

how i can make T[] field?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be write your question with care and avoid typos (Title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stumbled upon a bug. Byte Buddy attempts to resolve `TargetType` references to identify the instrumented type's *self type* which is not done correctly for generic arrays. It will be fixed in the next version 1.10.11.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. However, if you want, you can do this:

```
Object[] value = new Object[];
```

Then when accessing it:

```
T t = (T) value[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

One option i found that works, is to use the field in class `Clazz<T>` as a prototype to defined the new field:

```
Unloaded<Object> cls = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).typeVariable("T")
            .defineField("value", Clazz.class.getDeclaredFields()[0].getGenericType(), Modifier.PUBLIC);
```